# Scala Future exception contract compared to Objective-C NSError **

Tags: objective-c, scala, playframework

I have strong Objective-C background and I'm trying to write Scala.
In Objective-C exceptions are used to indicate unrecoverable (mostly) errors. And there is NSError ** contract in methods which could result in an error.

Given Play WebServices what exceptions should I expect if the future fails? Where is the contract?

Answer (score 0):

`Future` represents its success and failure cases using `scala.util.Success` and `scala.util.Failure` respectively.

You can see in the docs that `Failure` holds a `Throwable`, so any exception occured in the execution of the `Future` will be wrapped into a `Failure` value.

So there's no contract specifying the kind of exception a failed `Future` can hold: you can expect any `Throwable` instance.

Even in `Objective-C` there's no formal contract indicating which kind of `NSError` to expect. You simply know that a computation can fail (synchronously in that case), and that's the same thing a `Future` does (although asynchronously)

Comment: Yes. I know that. The question is what exception to expect in recover

Comment: See my update. Basically, any exception that can happen in the execution of the `Future`. There's no contract other than the fact that `Failure` will hold a `Throwable`.

Comment: There is contract in objective-c because there is an error domain of library/framework.

Comment: That is far from formal. Technically you could encounter any error.